# How to use fragments from a grid view?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I am trying to make a gallery of images in my app, I have this currently as a grid view then passing to a full image view via ImageAdapter.

The problem is I want to be able to swipe between pictures after clicking from the grid view.

Someone has mentioned I might be able to use fragments to do this but I am new to android development.

Can someone please explain further on how to do this. Thanks

The code I have is:

```
    public class Marble extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.marble);

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter1(this));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity1.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

then

```
public class FullImageActivity1 extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter1 imageAdapter1 = new ImageAdapter1(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter1.mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
public class ImageAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.arabescato, R.drawable.biancocarrara,
            R.drawable.botticinoclassico, R.drawable.calacattaoro,
            R.drawable.cremamarfil, R.drawable.cremavalencia,
            R.drawable.emperadordark, R.drawable.jurabeige,
            R.drawable.neromarquina, R.drawable.perlatoolympo,
            R.drawable.rojoalicante

    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter1(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(265, 265));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of image view put a view pager in your FullImageActivity1

```
this.mPagerfrimage = new pagerfrimage(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                list of drawables here);
        ViewPager vp_image = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
        vp_image.setAdapter(mPagerfrimage);
```

this is the pager adapter calss

```
class pagerfrimage extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    List<Integer> la;

    public pagerfrimage(FragmentManager fm, List<Integer> result) {
        super(fm);
        this.la = result;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fragmentforimage ffrFragmentforimage = new fragmentforimage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("resourceid", la.get(arg0));
        bundle.putInt("number", arg0);
        ffrFragmentforimage.setArguments(bundle);
        return ffrFragmentforimage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return la.size();
    }



}
```

fragment class

```
public class fragmentforimage extends Fragment {
int number;
int resourceid;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        resourceid=getArguments()!=null?getArguments().getInt("resourceid"):0;
        number=getArguments()!=null?getArguments().getInt("number"):0;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayot containing image view, container, false);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.your imageviews id);
        Drawable drawable=getResources().getDrawable(resourceid);
            iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            return v;}
```

you can pass the current selected image id so you will be able to show that at first change the code as per your need

Comment: Where you've put your imageviews here: ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.your imageviews id);  do I need to make a view for each picture? I have about 100!

Comment: no you just need to create a single layout with an image view which will be inflated each time  View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayot containing image view, container, false); and the image view in this layout should be used

Comment: excellent, sorry really new to this! Have I done this part right? this.mPagerfrimage = new pagerfrimage(getSupportFragmentManager(),
    R.drawable.arabescato, R.drawable.biancocarrara,
             R.drawable.botticinoclassico, R.drawable.calacattaoro,
             R.drawable.cremamarfil, R.drawable.cremavalencia,
             R.drawable.emperadordark, R.drawable.jurabeige,
             R.drawable.neromarquina, R.drawable.perlatoolympo,
             R.drawable.rojoalicante);
        ViewPager vp_image = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        vp_image.setAdapter(mPagerfrimage);

Comment: no you should add it in a list like List<Integer> a=new Vector<Integer>();
a.add(R.drawable.biancocarrara);.... and pass the list in the cunstroctor

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/

Comment: cheers, I'll check that out as I'm still getting errors with this.mPagerfrimage = new pagerfrimage(getSupportFragmentManager(),
  List<Integer> a=new Vector<Integer>(); a.add(R.drawable.biancocarrara);
        ViewPager vp_image = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        vp_image.setAdapter(mPagerfrimage);

Comment: the m pager have to be declared erlier :) check it out any way go step by step so you understands each line of code and can advice someone else and help them :)